# How to retrieve full subject list from the Google Books API?

Tags: google-api, google-books

When I perform a `Volume: get search` or a `Volume: list` using the Google Books API, I'm not getting the full subject list back. [The API returns](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/cTiYAgAAQBAJ):

```
categories: [
    "Fiction / General"
],
```

And [this is what the Google Books record shows](https://books.google.ca/books/about/The_Miniaturist.html?id=LjhOnwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y):

```
Subjects
Fiction > Thrillers > Suspense

Fiction / Historical
Fiction / Literary
Fiction / Thrillers / Suspense
```

Has anyone encountered this before and knows how I can get this full subject list back?

Comment: Hi @Kait, any luck on this one?

Comment: Hi @AvihooMamka - unfortunately not, I couldn't figure out a workaround :(